# How to change all volume types from hostPath to nfs in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

Currently, my cluster uses hostPath as the volume type. I want to change all volume types from hostPath to nfs and create pvc for every volume. How can I do this without losing data?

```
Information:
Kubernetes version: 1.22.2
Installation method: bare-metal
Host OS: Ubuntu 20.04
CNI and version: Flannel 0.15.0
CRI and version: Docker 20.10.9
```

Comment: You actually need a migration from hostpath to the nfs. Hostpath and NFS can behave differently depending on your scenario. Make a good plan for this. Test it, if it behaves as expected.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you for your response. That's right, I need some migration. The first thing I tried was: 1-Create PVC for volumes. 2-Copy data from hostpath directory to nfs directory(or PVC's directory). 3-Changed deployment volume from hostpath to nfs. It worked, but I wanted to know if there is any better solution.

Comment: Ok. But I guess not. At least i also haven't seen any.